# How do you get text from a textbox with databinding propertynotifying thingy mvvm light

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

- I have a username and password box.
- Underneath it I have a button.
- When I click that button I want to analyse what has been put into the username and password box.

***How do I do this with mvvm light?***

This is where I am:

**XAML**

```
...DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">...
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,27,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Username}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,126,0,0" Password="{Binding Password}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>

        <Button Content="Log in" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="167,203,169,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding LogInCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
```

**View Model**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public LoginCredentials LoginCredentials { get; set; }        
    public ICommand LogInCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        LoginCredentials = new LoginCredentials();
        LogInCommand = new RelayCommand(this.OnLogInCommand);
    }

    private void OnLogInCommand()
    {
        string testUsername = Username;
        string testPassword = Password;
    }

    #region Properties
    public string Username
    {
        get { return LoginCredentials.Username; }
        set { LoginCredentials.Password = value; }
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get { return LoginCredentials.Password; }
        set { LoginCredentials.Password = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**what is happening at the moment:**

- When I click my button, the *LogInCommand* is run and it fires my method *OnLoginCommand*. I have put a break point on the testUsername declaration to see if when the button is clicked, the username and password reflect what has been put in; they are both empty. What must I do to make sure these are updated as someone is typing or when the button is pressed or however it works???

I have now spent about 4 weeks learning mvvm and trying to get a simple click event and binding to work. This is simply not making sense... doh. Thanks for any help!

**P.S** - Is MVVM light too confusing for new comers? the documentation is so.. light on detail. No examples :(

Comment: Check this tutorial first: http://blog.micic.ch/net/easy-mvvm-example-with-inotifypropertychanged-and-inotifydataerrorinfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View**

Windows Phone doesn't contain "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged". You have to use "**Explicit**" and manually call "**UpdateSource**" in code behind, otherwise value of TextBox/PasswordBox will be raise when TextBox/PasswordBox lost focus.

And don't forget to set "**Mode=TwoWay**".

```
<TextBox
    Text="{Binding Path=Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
    TextChanged="TextBoxTextChanged" />

<PasswordBox
    Password="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
    PasswordChanged="PasswordBoxPasswordChanged" />

<Button
    Command="{Binding Path=LogInCommand}"
    Content="Log in" />
```

**View - code behind**

```
private void PasswordBoxPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PasswordBox pb = sender as PasswordBox;

    if (pb != null)
    {
        pb.GetBindingExpression(PasswordBox.PasswordProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
}


private void TextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

Fields

```
private RelayCommand _logInCommand;
private string _password;
private string _username;
```

Properties

```
public bool CanExecuteLogInCommand
{
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Username) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Password);
    }
}

    public RelayCommand LogInCommand
    {
        get
        {
            // or you can create instance in constructor: this.LogInCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecuteLogInCommand, () => this.CanExecuteLogInCommand);
            return this._logInCommand ?? (this._logInCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecuteLogInCommand, () => this.CanExecuteLogInCommand));
        }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get { return this._username; }

        set
        {
            // a) shorter alternative -> "True if the PropertyChanged event has been raised, false otherwise"
            if (this.Set(() => this.Username, ref this._username, value))
            {
                // raise CanExecuteLogInCommand
                this.LogInCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }


            // b) longer alternative
            //if (value == this._username) { return; }

            //this._username = value;

            //this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Username);
            //this.LogInCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return this._password; }

        set
        {
            if (this.Set(() => this.Password, ref this._password, value))
            {
                this.LogInCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Methods

```
    private void ExecuteLogInCommand()
    {
        // .... = this.Username;
        // .... = this.Password;
    }
```

Check this **[sample](http://sdrv.ms/1hyANmi)**.

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps model supports `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. [Simple working version.](https://github.com/BlueWhaleSEO/.NET/blob/master/DonatasSimpleUniversal_MVVM_App/DonatasSimpleUniversal_MVVM_App/DonatasSimpleUniversal_MVVM_App.WindowsPhone/MainPage.xaml)

Answer (score 0):

To get the View and ViewModel 'linked up' so that they are synchronized, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (Encapsulated in ViewModelBase). i.e.:

```
private string userName;
public string UserName
{
    get { return userName; }
    set
    {
        if (value != userName)
        {
            userName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }
}
```